# How does HBase guarantee row level atomicity?

Tags: database, nosql, hadoop, hbase, distributed-system

Considering the fact that HBase stores each column family in a separate HFile and the fact that a row can span many Column Families. How does HBase ensure that a put/delete operation on a row that spans multiple column families is indeed atomic ?

Comment: As far as I know, for any row operation (such as Put/Delete/checkAndPut) the operation order is append -> sync -> memstore. And also there is a timestamp in every KeyValue, in which you can store multiple versions of KeyValue pairs inside a column family (determined by the column family's version). You can also use a RowLock to be sure that operation is totally safe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All writes to the a row, no matter how many column families might be in that row, go to one regionserver, and that regionserver then writes the edit to the regions WAL (Hlog), then the writes are sync'd, then the data is added to the memstore so it will be served. Then - once the memstore has hit its limit - the memstore be flushed to disk. If any problems occur to the regionserver and it crashes/dies/has the plug pulled the WAL can be run through to keep everything consistant. For more gory details see the [HBASE-2283](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-2283) and [Hbase Architecture 101](http://www.larsgeorge.com/2010/01/hbase-architecture-101-write-ahead-log.html).

Comment: Thank you for the links. I was actually interested in how HBase ensures that write to all the HFiles (there will be multiple HFiles involved if more than 1 column family is touched for a Put/Delete call) happens atomically. But like you mentioned, since that update can still be retrieved from the WAL, HBase could guarantee atomicity for its clients.

Comment: Exactly - the WAL is used to get around the multiple hfile problem, among other things.

Answer (score 1):

HBase currently achieves row-level atomicity in spite of writing multiple HFiles by flushing all column families at the same time. The flush is triggered when the biggest column family reaches the configured flush size. There is an additional MemStore-level timestamp that allows to do multi-version concurrency control for MemStore reads, but that does not exist for key/values that are written to HFiles. Switching to per-column-family flush (a desirable feature for improving efficiency) would require a similar timestamp to be added to the file format as well.